WndProc for newly created forms
I need to have all the new forms created based on a custom config that determines how many forms are needed to have the same features (icon and custom menu actions). I get CS1540 error on form.WndProc += (ref Message m) => line.
    private void SetupSystemMenu(Form form)
    {
    // Add your icon to the form (if applicable)
    form.Icon = this.Icon;

    // Hook into the form's HandleCreated event to set up the system menu
    form.HandleCreated += (sender, e) =>
    {
        IntPtr systemMenuHandle = GetSystemMenu(form.Handle, false);

        // Add a separator and then our custom items
        AppendMenu(systemMenuHandle, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, string.Empty);
        AppendMenu(systemMenuHandle, MF_STRING, SYSMENU_CUSTOM_ITEM_ID, "Erase Config");
        AppendMenu(systemMenuHandle, MF_STRING, SYSMENU_PAUSE_TIMER_ID, "Pause Timer");
        AppendMenu(systemMenuHandle, MF_STRING, SYSMENU_REFRESH_NOW_ID, "Refresh Now");
    };

    // Hook into the WndProc of the form to handle menu item clicks
    form.WndProc += (ref Message m) =>
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
        {
            switch (m.WParam.ToInt32())
            {
                case SYSMENU_CUSTOM_ITEM_ID:
                    EraseConfig();
                    break;

                case SYSMENU_PAUSE_TIMER_ID:
                    ToggleTimerPause();
                    break;

                case SYSMENU_REFRESH_NOW_ID:
                    Program.refreshRequested = true;
                    refreshTimer.Stop();
                    form.Close();
                    break;
            }
        }
        form.WndProc(ref m);
    };
}


WndProc is a method, not an event.

I see, how can I get this method to work for form1 and all forms created via currentForm = new Form();
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m), can I pass forms to this so all have the same behaviour?

If you have a single Form and you create instances from it, just override its own WndProc . If you have different Forms, then use a base class for all, and override WndProc in the base Form class only -- In case you're interested: How to show menu item with icon AND text in WinForms system menu (see also the HandleMessage() / OnSysCommandMessage() methods and the in-code comments you find there)
